# How to show a Cauchy problem maximal solution does not live forever

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the Cauchy problem \begin{cases} y'=y^2-2y\sin(y)\\y(0)=a,  \end{cases}
with $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $c$ be the positive solution of $y^2-2y\sin(y)=0$. I've shown that if $a\in[-c, c]$ then the solution to the Cauchy problem can be extended globally on $\mathbb{R}$. My question is: what happens when $a\not \in [-c, c]$ ? I think the maximal solution does not live forever. Can we use the method of upper and lower solutions?

Comment: OP: What did you find when $y(0)<-c$ (the case left to you)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three constant solutions, $y=0$ and $y=\pm c$, with $c$ being the only positive root of $\sin x-\frac{x}{2}$. All the solutions with an initial condition $y(0)\in(0,c)$ or $y(0)\in(-c,0)$ live forever, since solutions cannot cross each other. To study the life span of all the other solutions, we just need to consider that our DE is separable, so any solution is given by the inverse function of 
$$ g(x)=\int_{x_0}^{x}\frac{1}{t^2-2t\sin t}\,dt. $$
It is useful to draw the graphics of the integrand function:

$\hspace1in$[image]

to recognize two non-integrable singularities (simple poles) at $x=\pm c$.

Since $y(0)>c$ grants $y'>0$, the life span of a solution with such an initial condition is exactly:

$$ \int_{y(0)}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t^2-2t\sin t}\,dt < +\infty $$
and the integral can be estimated pretty easily.

I leave to you to study the remaining case $y(0)<-c$.